# Porque No Busca en la Base de Datos PHP con COMBOX

Tags: php

Hola a todos por favor alguien me pude decir por que cuando selecciono una region del combox no me busca en la base de datos el registro???
ya lo intente de varias formas y no me queda, en una caja de texto si me envia el registro cuando pongo la clave, 
pero al seleccionarlo de la lista no funciona ni con enter ni con el boton.

Esta es la parte principal donde tengo una caja de texto y el combox

```
    <form  action = "consultadirecta.php" method="POST" >
    Seccion: <input type="tex" name="txtclave" ></br>

<select name="txtregion">
<option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
<?php

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla1 GROUP BY region HAVING COUNT(*)>1" ) ;
while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
echo '<option value="'.$valores['ID'].'">'.$valores['Region'].'</option>';
          }
?>
</select>

</br>
    <input type="submit" value="buscar" name="btnbuscar">

</form>
```

En esta seccion hago la consulta, coloque las dos variables para que reciba el dato, la de la caja de texto y la del combox pero no funciona

```
<?php

    include ("conexion.php");
    $clave = isset($_POST['txtclave']) ? $_POST['txtclave'] : null;  
    $region = isset($_POST['txtregion']) ? $_POST['txtregion'] : null;  


        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * from tabla1 WHERE Clave='$clave' or Region='$region' " ) 
        or die ("Error al traer datos");

            echo '<table border="1">';
            echo '<th id = "id">ID</th>'; 
            echo '<th id = "clave">clave</th>';
            echo '<th id = "region">region</th>';
            echo '<th id = "encuestador">encuestador</th>';
            echo '<th id = "encuestado">encuestado</th>';
            echo '</tr>';

        while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
        {
            echo '<tr>'; 
            echo '<td>'.$extraido['ID'].'</td>'; 
            echo '<td>'.$extraido['clave'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$extraido['region'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$extraido['encuestador'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$extraido['encuestado'].'</td>';
            >";
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo '</table>';

    ?>
```

Comment: La variable `$region` no existe.  Deberia de ser `$localidad`.

Comment: transcribí mal esa parte ya lo corregí, agradecido por  observación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el select retorna valores de la columna `ID` y estas buscando en la columna `Region`.  La solucion es cambiar el `value` de los options a la columna `Region`:

```
echo '<option value="'.$valores['Region'].'">'.$valores['Region'].'</option>';.
```

o buscar por la columna `ID`:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * from tabla1 WHERE Clave='$clave' or ID='$region' " )
```

Comment: Te agradesco alanfcm voy a chekar y comento

Comment: Funcionooooooo !!! nuevamente GRACIAS!!!  alanfcm llevaba horas intentandolo y no quedaba.